# Does a query to an ScriptDb consume quotas?

Tags: google-apps-script

In the official documentation of ScriptDb is well documented the storage capabilities of the ScriptDb. However, it is not clear for me if querying a ScriptDb or saving new objects to an ScriptDb consumes quotas. Is there a limit in the number of queries that an app can do to an ScriptDb per day?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ScritpDb is only capped by overall store size [starts at 50mb](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/scriptdb) and is the total of all the databases owned by the script author.

The only thing you'll want to be sure with reads is that it doesn't run over on execution times (usually if a script runs for several minutes you should be concerned). For example, the total [trigger execution time](https://script.google.com/dashboard) for a day is 1hr. If you run the script as the person accessing the script then you'll be less likely to run into this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there a way to know the execution time of an script? Does the tasks performed on the user side (such as form validations with javascript, html generation, jQuery functionality, etc) count as part of this execution time?

Comment: No, tasks performed on the user side does not count against this execution time.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply.

Comment: Forgot to answer the first question - there is no good way to see the execution time on a dashboard today. You'll have to track it to see if you are getting close to the limit.